# clone syscall - can i deallocate stack memory in parent process?

Tags: linux, system-calls

Is it safe to deallocate stack buffer passed to `child_stack` argument of `clone` in parent process after `clone` returns(in case `CLONE_VM` is not specified)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [clone man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html):

> If CLONE_VM is not set, the child process runs in a separate copy of
>   the memory space of the calling process at the time of clone(). Memory
>   writes or file mappings/unmappings performed by one of the processes
>   do not affect the other, as with fork(2).

This also includes `child_stack`, it was just duplicated like everything else.

So yes, the parent can deallocate it, the child uses a copy, not the original anymore.